# Is it solvable to ask to find a recurrence relation for the following sequence 4,7,2,20,31,73,155,332,715,... ?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it solvable to ask to find a recurrence relation for the following sequence 4,7,2,20,31,73,155,332,715,...  without any other information? If not, what would be the very least amount of information for me to give someone for them to arrive at $f_n=f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}+f_{n-3}$?

Comment: Is $f(0)=4,f(1)=7,\cdots f(\text{something})715, f(n)=f(n-1)\forall \, n>\text{something}$ a valid answer?

Comment: I was thinking I have to say find a homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients. But I guess I want to know is there a way to determine the coefficients are constant given I say the recurrence relation is homogeneous? But I also want to know if I can get away with saying a lot less? :p

Comment: Similar to my statement that giving the extra three values can let you tell them it is a sixth order recurrence, you can use the three values to limit the inhomogeneous part.  If you say the inhomogeneous part has degree $2$ or less, they can find it is $0$.  You could alternatively allow some variation in the coefficients that the extra three values can rule out, but I haven't thought about how much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tell them the numbers satisfy a third order linear homogeneous recurrence that is certainly enough.  They can then write $f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}+cf_{n-3}$ and solve three simultaneous equations to find $a,b,c$.  You have given three more values than required for that, so you could tell them it is a sixth order recurrence and expect them to find that the top three terms are zero.

Comment: Yes that was my thoughts too... I was just trying to make it harder without making it impossible.

Comment: Sometimes I like to make really difficult problems for my friends to solve that I can actually solve? When making this problem, I said this would be impossible for me to solve myself without giving myself the information that the recurrence is homogeneous and the coefficients of the terms of that recurrence is constant. I'm really starting to think there is no way around it. I think they might be able to guess the third order part because the sequence does have a sudden increase and doesn't stop after the third term so I think that the order doesn't need to be given.

Comment: Ross, Conway and Guy and Sloane came up with a mechanical method for detecting linear recurrences with constant coefficients. This finds the degree for us. I put an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mechanical technique for detecting linear recurrences without knowing the degree ahead of time. It is about pages 86,87 of *The Book of Numbers* by Conway and Guy. I do not have the book, so I got it from a book review. They call the technique the Number Wall. The nice part is that, if the sequence is integers, the entries remain integers. For a wall made up of bricks, for each little cross of five bricks, 
$$
\begin{array}{rrr}
  & N & \\
  W & C & E \\
  & S & \\
\end{array}
$$
we calculate the new $S$ value by the requirement
$$ NS + WE = C^2.  $$ We start at the top with a row of ones, the next row is the unknown sequence. We continue top down. The rule says
$$ S = (C^2 - WE)/ N $$

$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 7 & 2 & 20 & 31 & 73 & 155 & 332 & 715 \\
 & 41 & -136 & 338 & -499 & 524 & -211 & -601 &  \\
 &  & 2319 & 2319 & 2319 & 2319 & 2319 &  &  \\
 &  &  & 0 & 0 & 0 &  &  &  \\
\end{array}
$$
The rule says that the number of rows to get from the unknown sequence to a row of $0'$s is the degree of the recurrence. If that happens, you should recover the constant coefficients (linear algebra) and try to prove that it works, or maybe prove that it was a coincidence and there is no nice recurrence. You have degree three. Evidently there is also detail in *A Handbook of Integer Sequences* by Neil Sloane. In particular, extra rules are needed when the wall contains a little  square of zeroes, which they call a "window."

[image]

Comment: Haha, this is such a nice trick to know! I don't want to go offtopic with respect to the original question, but there is a sentence in your scanned page that says *"If standard differencing techniques do not reveal the rule behind a sequence, then the sequence cannot be of polynomial type."* What are the "standard differencing techniques", please?

Comment: @AlexM. sometimes called the calculus of finite differences. If you list the squares, in order, in a row, then write the differences of consecutive terms in a row just below, you get odd numbers. The next row of differences are all $2.$ The final row are all $0,$ which says degree two. Start over with a row of consecutive cubes. Take differences of consecutive terms. Do that again. In just a few rows you get a row with all entries equal to $6.$ try both

Comment: @AlexM. looked at your profile. If your beginning row really is of the form $f(n)$ where $f$ is a polynomial, the next row is $f(n+1) - f(n),$ which is a polynomial of lower degree.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up the problen like this?

$$f_{n-3}=\frac{1}{2}(f_{n}-f_{n-1}-f_{n-2})$$

Where you replace the $f_{n}$'s with variables.

I think it's enough of a hint and shows the key inductive step needed to solve the problem but still requires you to see the relationship of the recurrance for yourself?